# How to Consider NOTHING in VB.Net to NULL in SQL Server via NULLABLE Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, nullable, dbnull

Parameters in Stored Procedure are `@classid INT = NULL, @streamid INT = NULL`. Now in VB.NET I have declared two variable `Dim classid As Int32?, streamid As Int32?` as `NULLABLE`. If no value is passed to these parameters then it pass `NOTHING`.

Does `NOTHING` is considered as `NULL` in SQL Server or I have to pass `DBNULL.Value` explicity from code while passing parameters to SP?

Because when I am executing my SP directly from SQL Server then it showing me results but if I am calling my SP from application then it showing me no records.

Passing the parameters from Code:

```
cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", classid.GetValueOrDefault())
cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stream", streamid.GetValueOrDefault())
```

I am passing both the parameters as above.

Comment: Either specify explicit `DBNull.Value` for a null .NET value or omit the parameter entirely so the proc default is used.

Comment: Note that ADO.NET was designed before nullable value types was a thing, so `DBNull` was specifically created because there was no way to indicate no value for a value type. ADO.NET wasn't going to be redesigned when nullable value types were introduced, so we're stuck with it. If you use some sort of wrapper for the standard ADO.NET types, like EF or even a typed `DataSet`, then you can use `Nothing` at that level, but they will still map to `DBNull.Value` under the hood.

Comment: I think you might be doubly-wrong here, so to speak. Not only is a SQL `null` different from a .net `null` (as Dan mentioned, the .net equivalent is `DBNull.Value`), but also, by asking for `GetValueOrDefault()` you're not even going to get a .net `null`, you're actually going to get 0... which, honestly, is not at all clear in the docs, because the default value for an `int?` is `null`, but `GetValueOrDefault` returns the default of the *underlying* type.

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault()` on a nullable int is `0`. That's not what you want. [Nor is `AddWithValue` a good idea](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(classid.HasValue, CObj(classid.Value), DBNull.Value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1:** parameters you declared in **stored procedure** are

```
@classid INT = NULL, 
@streamid INT = NULL
```

but passing parameters from **VB.Net** are

```
@class
@stream
```

you must have the **same parameters** in boths sides to keep it working.

**2:** parameters should be declared as

```
@classid INT NULL, 
@streamid INT NULL
```

Comment: then from vb how should I pass null to parameter if variable is equal to nothing?

Comment: actually `Null` in this context means you can use this SP without passing parameters to it as well.

Comment: While you're right about the parameter names not lining up, the correct way to specify a stored procedure parameter with a default value *is* to use the equals sign, ie `create procedure p (@i int = null) as ...`. The syntax is legal without the `=`, but that does not specify a default value for the parameter

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) you're supposed to use `DBNull.Value`:

> **value** Object
>
> The value to be added. Use [[DBNull.]Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instead of null, to indicate a null value.

It's quite possible that `Nothing` (`null` in C#) works as well, but according to the documentation, it's not officially supported.

---

Side note: you have a bug in your code:

> cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", classid.GetValueOrDefault())

Here, you don't pass `Nothing`, you pass `0`, because `GetValueOrDefault()` converts `Nothing` to the underlying data type's default value (`0` in the case of `Int32?`).

To pass either an Int32 or Nothing, use

```
cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", classid)
```

To pass either an Int32 or DBNull.Value, use

```
cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", If(CObj(classid), DBNull.Value))
```

<sup>(`CObj` is required with `Option Strict On` to allow `If` to infer a common return type.)</sup>